# Roscpp header file for tf2 transform

Tags: ros, include, tf2, package.xml, roscpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Which header file to include for tf2::Transform? Unfortunately this is not a well documented way to use tf2 as far as I can find. It is in the file `Transform.h`, but that file can't be included as such: `<tf2/Transform.h>` or `<tf2/LinearMath/Transform.h>`

Should I revert to using tf? Is this not a canonical way to use tf2?

Cheers!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/257068/roscpp-header-file-for-tf2-transform/) by [errolflynn](https://answers.ros.org/users/26799/errolflynn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 32 on 2017-03-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The tf2::Transform is in `<tf2/LinearMath/Transform.h>` [here](https://github.com/ros/geometry2/blob/indigo-devel/tf2/include/tf2/LinearMath/Transform.h#L32).  My guess is that you are not adding the correct paths to your include directories in you CMakeLists.txt

Note that in general it's recommended to use a standalone linear math library like [eigen](http://wiki.ros.org/eigen) or [bullet](http://www.continuousphysics.com/Bullet/BulletFull/index.html) or [kdl](http://www.orocos.org/kdl)

You can used packages like [tf2_bullet](http://wiki.ros.org/tf2_bullet) or  [tf2_eigen](http://wiki.ros.org/tf2_eigen) or  [tf2_kdl](http://wiki.ros.org/tf2_kdl)

Or you can add support for your own datatypes: http://wiki.ros.org/tf2/Tutorials/Create%20Data%20Conversion%20Package%20%28C%2B%2B%29

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2017-03-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [errolflynn](https://answers.ros.org/users/26799/errolflynn/) on 2017-03-15**:
Thank you. Any reasons why to use specifically one of those options over the other?

**Comment by [Airuno2L](https://answers.ros.org/users/458/airuno2l/) on 2017-03-15**:
I like eigen because it is more general purpose and is easy to use (IMO).

**Comment by [errolflynn](https://answers.ros.org/users/26799/errolflynn/) on 2017-03-16**:
What is include header for tf2_eigen?

**Comment by [Airuno2L](https://answers.ros.org/users/458/airuno2l/) on 2017-03-17**:
is it not [tf2_eigen.h](http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/tf2_eigen/html/tf2__eigen_8h.html) ?

**Comment by [errolflynn](https://answers.ros.org/users/26799/errolflynn/) on 2017-03-17**:
Getting the message `fatal error: tf2_eigen/tf2_eigen.h: No such file or directory #include <tf2_eigen/tf2_eigen.h>`

**Comment by [errolflynn](https://answers.ros.org/users/26799/errolflynn/) on 2017-03-17**:
Not getting the same error for `tf2_kdl/tf2_kdl.h`

**Comment by [errolflynn](https://answers.ros.org/users/26799/errolflynn/) on 2017-03-17**:
Solved: It's because I didn't have `tf2_eigen` installed